# Sqlite DB approach

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I am developing a simple accounting sofware to manage credit history of customers, I don't have much programming experience just 6 months for now. So my question is very trivial.

There is a table named `BILLING` for persisting all the bills. It has `sum_total_amount` and `received_amount` fields.

Now for a transaction `balance_amount = sum_total_amount - received_amount`

There is also a `CUSTOMER` table for persisting customer information.

Now for summing up `balance_amount` over mutiple transactions, I see two approaches

1. Have a field in `CUSTOMER` table say `balance_amount` and update it over every transaction
2. Compute `balance_amount` as a query `select sum(sum_total_amount - received_amount) from BILLING where customer_id = ?;`

Which approach would be better ?

Comment: My personal opinion, but I prefer not to store calculated data in my tables. Just add the overhead of updating that data at the time of transaction.

Comment: Do you have this data on the server from an existing accounting/finance system and you are trying to give field personnel access to it?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of database theory, you need to consider whether `balance_amount` belongs to the customer or the account. It sounds like `balance_amount` would be an account property and would be queried using a customer id.

That said, in terms of resource use, both ways will work without noticeable differences.